# JSON.parse issue in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api

I am performing a get request to a url that returns a simple JSON object.

Here is the URL: http://live.albiononline.com/status.txt

As you can see it is a text file and it's content-type header is text/plain. When I receive the body log it, it is:

`{ "status": "online", "message": "All good." }`

But when I try to log, body.status it is undefined. When I do `var data = JSON.parse(body);` then `console.log(data.status);` I get:

```
undefined:1
{ "status": "online", "message": "All good." }
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
```

Any idea what's happening? I assume it has something to do with the fact it's pulling from a .txt file?

**UPDATE:**

```
request('http://live.albiononline.com/status.txt', function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(body); // { "status": "online", "message": "All good." }
                console.log(body.status); // undefined
            }
        });
```

Comment: It's already JSON object. You don't need to parse

Comment: In my question I said, 'But when I try to log, body.status it is undefined.'

Comment: can you show me your code once

Comment: added code to question

Comment: Try doing `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body)).status`

Comment: it is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because the output is not a stringified JSON object, it's just a normal string.

The output I got while working on your example code:

```
'{ "status": "online", "message": "All good." }\r\n'
```

A real JSON string wouldn't have extra spaces and escape characters at the end.

Solution:

```
x=x.trim(); // trimming off the \r\n
var output = JSON.parse(x); // parsing the JSON
```

Comment: Hmm. So how do I parse it as an object?

Comment: This is the answer, trim off the \r\n before JSON.parse()

Comment: You're a life saver. Thank you very much!